# Android : Child layouts occupying the whole width of screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a linear layout as a parent layout with three child layouts and I am trying to show the images in child layouts by fetching from webservice.

Some of my images are occupying the whole width of the screen and It should not happen. how to avoid my child layouts occupying the whole width of the screen??

here is my code

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:baselineAligned="false"
  android:layout_weight="9">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/one"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>


   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/three"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have applied weight to your Linear layout,for weight to be applicable change the layout_width to **0dp**

Comment: Thanks,you mean the above code should be added  to parent layout??

Comment: you have to do this for the linear layout holding your imageview and set appropriate weight to it

Comment: Thanks,I have changed layout_width for all child layouts holding images views and  it didnt work,what values should be given for weight for all three child views??

Comment: post the whole code of your layout having imageview

Comment: I have a layout with image view and that is getting inflated inside my each child layouts via code and which icant show now.but the thing is some of the images are coming as i require and for some images the imageview width is occupying the whole layout.Dont know what to do here.

Comment: define layout parms and weight via code for your layouts

Comment: I have one final question is that happening because some images are bigger than the child layout/imageview ??

Comment: yes it can be but i can't be sure because i haven't seen the whole code of your layout ,but this may be the probable reason

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this

1. Add the imageviews in the layout and assign them width+height in dp

like so

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_weight="9">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
     .....

    <LinearLayout
     .....

</LinearLayout>
```

2. Play around with the scale values in

> ImageView.ScaleType

```
CENTER
Center the image in the view, but perform no scaling. 

CENTER_CROP 
Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding). 

CENTER_INSIDE
Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding). 

FIT_CENTER
Scale the image using CENTER.


FIT_END
Scale the image using END. 

FIT_START
Scale the image using START. 

FIT_XY
Scale the image using FILL. 

MATRIX 
Scale using the image matrix when drawing.
```

find more details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)